# Unbounded "polygon"

Tags: geometry, terminology

If we take the unit square and push its north-eastern corner to the north-east towards infinity, we end up with the first quarter-plane.

We can do the same to other polygons, for example, if we take this polygon:

[image]

and push point F north-eastwards, we end up with this infinite shape:

[image]

My question is simply: what term describes such infinite shapes? They are not polygons, not quarter-planes, so what are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such shapes  are called *unbounded polygonal domains*. They  frequently come up in conformal mapping problems involving Schwarz-Christoffel formula.

<sup>(I don't suppose you are looking for a term for the specific "quarterplane minus a square sharing a vertex with it" shape.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to specify that the polygonal domain is unbounded only in two sides, similar to a quarter-plane?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi I would try "polygonal domain with one vertex at infinity". Vertices are counted as we go around the domain; the description says we travel to infinity only once.

Comment: Aren't there (in this case exactly, and in general, at least)  two points at `infinity`? There needs to be an infinity for each direction that you can go to infinity.